# Bootstrap3 Navbar Link Positioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm running into an issue with my navbar and media queries. I can get it to switch from regular logo to a smaller logo with no problems. The visible-sm class is giving me issues as for the life of me, I cannot get the text links to the right to reduce the margin forcing the smaller logo up and making the navigation a horror. Did I miss something in the documentation? It seems like something really simple to reduce the rela estate the links are using when hitting the 767px media query. I apologize in advance if this has already been answered I couldn't find a question specific to this issue.
[Here be a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLUX.png)

[Here be the Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/T3LpLRgBLM/)

Here be my HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img src="images/logobug.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-sm" href="#"><img src="images/logosm.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-md" href="#"><img src="images/logomd.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="#"><img src="images/logolg.jpg" alt=" Logo" /></a>
        </a>

            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">

                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DIRECTIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SPONSERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VENUES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Here be my CSS:

```
    .navbar-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -25 px;
}
```

Comment: it's better to give a working code , I dont know why you are placing many logo you can use one logo and resize it with media screen

Comment: The problem is that with the resize the logo becomes too small and unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include Bootply link. OP edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what you want , I removed pull right because navbar right do the same
[a forked bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jCRvrY9gqE#)